# Unexpected Sheet Renaming in OpenPyXL When Only Case Changes

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm using OpenPyXL in Python to manipulate Excel workbooks. I encountered an unexpected behavior when renaming a sheet. **If I change the name of a sheet to a name that only differs in letter case from its previous name, OpenPyXL appends a '1' to the new name**.

Here is a Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
import openpyxl
# Create a new workbook
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
# Get the default sheet
sheet = wb.active
# Rename the sheet to 'Input (Raw)'
sheet.title = 'Input (Raw)'
# Rename the sheet to 'Input (raw)'
sheet.title = 'Input (raw)'
# Print the current title of the sheet
print(sheet.title)
```

Expected Output:

```
Input (raw)
```

Actual Output:

```
Input (raw)1
```

I'm using `Python 3.11.1` and `openpyxl 3.1.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation in the code when renaming or setting the Sheet title

```
"""
Set a sheet title, ensuring it is valid. 
Limited to 31 characters, no special characters. 
Duplicate titles will be incremented numerically
"""
```

So if the Sheet name is 'abc', when you change it to 'Abc' during the title rename the code will determine that there is a sheet already with the name 'Abc' even though it's the same one that will be renamed, and increment the new name by adding 1.

Arguably this is not a desired operation but that is how the code is written.
I guess you'll need to raise it with the Devs if you want it changed or re-write the code yourself; this check is made in the `avoid_duplicate_name` function in 'child.py'.
The function is a blind check i.e. it just checks if the new Sheet name matches (case insensitive) any existing Sheet name (from wb.worksheets list) and performs the increment if it does.

Modifying the code that calls 'avoid_duplicate_name' will fix the issue by removing the current Sheet name if it exists from the Sheets list so that the duplication check does not try a match against the original name.
Existing code in child.py (line 95, 3.1.2)

```
        if self.title is not None and self.title != value:
            value = avoid_duplicate_name(self.parent.sheetnames, value)
```

If the sheet already has a title then remove it from the Sheet list before performing the duplication check;

```
        if self.title is not None and self.title != value:
            sheet_list = self.parent.sheetnames
            if self.title:
                sheet_list.remove(self.title)
            value = avoid_duplicate_name(sheet_list, value)
```

<sup>*no guarantee that modifying openpyxl code wont break other operation</sup>

Of course you could also just use an intermediary name.

Comment: I've had a look at the Openpyxl issues and don't see that this situation has been raised.

Comment: I'll be using an intermediate title since my code is used on different computers at I only tell people to do `pip install -r requirements.txt`, so I cannot really change openpyxl source code on each computer easily.

Comment: I think this is a special case of `sheet.title = sheet.title`, which would have the same result. The code is very old and supposed to ape Excel and catch gotchas as much as anything else. "Fixing" it is possibly a lot more work than simply using an intermediary name. `sheet.title = "something odd"; sheet.title = "corrected"`

Comment: @Charlie Clark Yes that's exactly what I've done, I didn't think the problem was that deep, I thought it was me doing something wrong! But if it's a deep problem of `openpyxl` I won't be able to do much so that solution is ok albeit lowers readability for any dev working on my project but i've linked this stackoverflow next to this weird intermediary name so it might be ok

Comment: I don't it's a deep problem but it is a little tricky because the same code is used for renaming as adding new. The real issue is that it's an example of guard rails to stop people making a potential mess through typos, where I think that in general you don't want to be able to have different sheets with the same title but different capitalisatin. As Moken says, it's never come up as a bug, so I'd be tempted to let sleeping code lie.